# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified using TOAD client

Tags: database, error-handling, oracle10g, client, toad

I try to using connect with remote database using TOAD client. My oracle version is 10.2g. I follow these instructions that specified on this link, instead of step 13, because i cant understand what they explain  [link](http://avangari.wordpress.com/remote-oracle-database-access-using-instant-client-and-toad/). My Oracle TNS_ADMIN path is `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\ADMIN` and ORACLE_HOME is `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1`. I found may question regarding this query, but i am not found my answer.

Comment: What is in your `tnsnames.ora`, and how are you configuring the connection in Toad?

Comment: In `tnsnames.ora` describe the description of my connection. `TEST =
(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = TEST)))`

Answer (score 4):

We encountered this issue as well with Toad 10.x and Oracle Instant Client 11.2.x.  The (rather silly) solution for us was to add a comment to the very top of the tnsnames.ora file.  So for Step #8 in the linked instructions, the tnsnames.ora file would have this instead:

```
# Leave whitespace before your first entry below...

VIS =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <host_name or ip_address>)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SID = <instance_name>)
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
)
)
```

Comment: Don't understand the logic, neither can "accept" the answer but it did work for me too... +1

Answer (score 1):

Could you please verify your TOAD installation directory?

If it is something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\...`, the below link may help:

[Yves' Blog](http://www.synergys.ca/index.php?option=com_lyftenbloggie&category=installation&Itemid=68&lang=en)

Apparently there are issues when installing the 32 bit version of TOAD into a directory that contains '()' chracters.

Comment: I found the solution, there is one white space in TNS file, so that's it generate an error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was solved by removing extra white space connection name. there should be no white space in just before "TEST.CONN" and none of the other entries in tns file can have the same.

(No White Space)TEST.CONN=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=)
      (PORT=)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVICE_NAME=)
    )
  )